# Cookie not sending with Ajax request

Tags: cookies, azure, forms-authentication, cloud

Found an issue Forms authentication Cookie not sharing between the requests to service.

Cookie '.ASPXAUTH'generated and sent to Browser from the Login service successfully, but not sending the Cookie to consequent requests for the same service.

Found When Calling service from Cloud app the request using HTTP 1.1 and for Response it is HTTP 1.0

More observations with the user of Fiddler and other tools:

Working fine for the following circumstances:

1. Running Service and Client website from local development system
2. Hosting Service and Client on same IIS (local and remote)
3. Accessing based on URLs, cookies transmitted properly

Not working for the following circumstances:

1. Hosting service and Client in different IIS servers.
2. Hosting Service in IIS (or Azure) and Client from local development system

Some more details:
Both requests made for the same service i.e. same domain, same protocal, same port nr, etc.

**Updates at 20-12-2012 15:14:**

1. As I said earlier Login functionality working on Ajax call without fail, Fiddler shows the Set-Cookie on Response, but Browser not reading the Cookie.
2. Tried to read document.cookies on "complete:" event of $.Ajax(), where I unable to read the cookie. means browser not getting or holding the cookie (where Fiddler shows on the Response of the same)

Regards,
Ramakrishna

Comment: have you checked that your cookie is for the same protocol, domain, port and path

Comment: How many instances are you using?

Comment: Is the server (running IIS) time set to the current time? What is the timeout date and time for the cookie when using Azure or IIS?

Comment: Also, have you tried adding xhrFields:{withCredentials: true} in the $.ajax code? See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

Using the Forms Auth, have you performed some actions to take the ASP.NET Session out of process and out of server?

You cannot share the session between servers, so you have to either use SQL Session State provider and put session into SQL Azure, or use the Windows Azure Cache and provided Session State Provider to storage the session into a cache.

I'm sure you are good in using internet search engines, but here is a list of good articles to start with (taking the session out of process):

- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/wazplatformtrainingcourse_buildingappswithcacheservice_topic3.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg185668.aspx
- http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsazure/gg278339.aspx

Comment: Thanks astaykov for the reply,

As I mentioned i am not sharing the session between the server its on same Cloud app on the same server.